# On the plausibility of both sexes producing gametes on demand

Tags: internal-consistency, humanoid, reproduction

In most animals there is a different way of producing gametes: the male produces them "on demand" at the time of the reproductive act, while the female produces them on a roughly "fixed schedule", no matter if that coincides with a reproductive act or not.

For my fictional humanoid species I want to have both male and female sex being capable of producing the gametes "on demand", while still being viviparous.

Is there a way for explaining this without using magic or handwvavium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popular theory of menstruation is that it's [an evolutionary adaption to predatory fetuses](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20150420-why-do-women-have-periods) as some fetuses take too much blood and risk weakening the mother, and menstruation serves as a way to kill hostile fetuses or damaged ones that are a waste of resources.

You can just have the mother be fertile all the time, and always have eggs available, just that means bad fetuses will be able to grow more effectively, either weakening the mother or self aborting when they fail. This is risky for long pregnancies needed to make intelligent beings with powerful brains.

Your humanoid species might have adapted by having smaller babies that are less smart but physically adapt. This would make regular and quick pregnancy more feasible, as you could just dump lots of babies in the wild and hope for the best.

Comment: Menstruation is mostly only a primate thing (and not even all primates).  Most viviparous mammals simply reabsorb the uterine lining.  I don't know whether or not they reabsorb foetuses as you suggested, but either way, not menstruating is a totally normal thing for a mammal.

Answer (score 8):

### Induced ovulation

What you want is called [induced ovulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_ovulation_(animals)) and it is quite common in the animal kingdom with a large range of triggers. Cyclic/spontaneous production like that used by humans is favored by social species (where males are present in numbers all year round thus encouraging competition) but many social species instead have only induced ovulation instead and even species with both are common. There is no reason a fictional species could not have it.

Comment: Thank you! I just couldn't find the induced ovulation without the proper words for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Age and making your own**

It is certainly possible. The egg cells in the ovaries are formed at a certain time. For males this is different, as we cannot store enough sperm to last through the sexual mature years. Most would run dry in a week. Two and two together show that there is a formation period and that on demand production exists, thus is viable. We can double check this by looking at the formation period. A woman only needs to form one, albeit more specialised, egg cell in about a month. A man needs to create thousands of them in days. Due to the longer time, a woman can use this to create a single more specialised one.

The reasons can be a multitude, but most likely it's age. Currently people that are well off both get older, as well as get children when they're older. With menopause this means that at a certain moment you're getting closer to an undetermined time where you lose the ability to get kids. Strangely enough woman still have a lot of eggs left at this stage. If the humanoids had problems with getting kids on time due to the biological limits, it could have started an evolutionary pressure to generate egg cells on demand instead of storing them for life.

As far as I can see there is no reason not to generate on demand. There might be more complications, as the amount of created egg cells per cycle might accidentally exceed the normal amount, resulting in a multitude of kids for example. But otherwise it doesn't seem strange to have generation on demand, allowing immortal females to have children whenever in their lives.

Comment: Women are born with all their egg cells already made. What happens monthly is that one of the pre-formed egg-cells is selected and made ready to be fertilized; but normally no new egg cells are made during the woman's lifetime. (Except exceptions, which involve advanced biotechnology.)

Comment: @AlexP your additions are always appreciated. Unless you're suggesting that the embryo already has all egg cells stored, you're just repeating what I'm saying. Eggs are made at a certain time and then stored.

Comment: Both of you are repeating something that had been demonstrated as probably incorrect back in 2004: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/mouse-study-upends-bedroc/ Short version: they found stem cells in the ovaries can in fact produce new eggs.